# MonkeyC resource compiler does not recognize resources code, using eclipse with MonkeyC plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, garmin, connectiq

I am trying to experiment with making drawables in MonkeyC so i can make my own WatchFace. However, it does not seem that the resource compiler works, as it keeps popping this error:

```
BUILD: ERROR: D:\MonkeyC\O-face\source\OfaceView.mc:70:  extraneous input '<' expecting {<EOF>, 'using', '(', 'native', 'static', 'hidden', 'var', 'const', 'class', 'function', 'module', 'enum'}
```

This is my relevant piece of code:

```
<resources>
    <drawable-list id="Post" x ="30" y ="30" width = "40" height = "40" background="Gfx.COLOR_BLACK">
        <shape type="Polygon" x="37" y="3" points = "3" width = "34" height = "34" color="Gfx.COLOR_ORANGE" />
        <shape type="Polygon" x="3" y="3" points = "3" width = "34" height = "34" color="Gfx.COLOR_WHITE" />
    </drawable-list>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have that XML code above within a file named OfaceView.mc (which is what appears to be the case) then the compiler is treating the file as a MonkeyC file (due to the .mc file extension). The XML you have should be within the resources directory/folder within a file that has a file extension of .xml